# Codeigniter 404 status header with no reason

Tags: codeigniter, http-headers

Hello all
I have a controller which calls a model which returns after a db query an array to my view which prints some json which i can see in my browser.The problem is that this page has a 404 status header for no reason.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You would probably get a better answer if you added all relevant code to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page that shouldn't exist is often sends a 404 header in CodeIgniter.

You could do one of the following

- Check if you the controller/method exists
- Check if you have any routing that may be pointing you to another controller/method
- Check if that location can be browsed via a browser

If nothing works, it would be better if you posted some of your code, routing, etc that may help.

Comment: Altough the header is 404 the page is served normally.Thanks though